# Bootstrap accordion-group need to retain collapse state after postback

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar which collapses/expands 3 accordion-groups dis (working so far).
There is a button in the div which triggers a postback after the data is returned from the code behind; the div is now collapsed and not visible unless the users clicks on the navbar option again.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordiongroup" runat="server">
   <div class="accordion-group" id="dvAccGrp" >
     <div id="allAccess" class="collapse mt-5 pt-3"  data-parent="#CollapseGrp" runat="server">
         <h4>User All Access</h4>
         <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" runat="server" id="btnAA" OnClick="btnAA_ServerClick" Text="Refresh" />
         <asp:GridView id="grvAllAccess" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped pt-2" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnPreRender="grvAllAccess_PreRender" ></asp:GridView>
         <hr />
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" id="btnAACx" onserverclick="btnAACx_ServerClick">Reset Selected User</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be that in your postback function use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and invoke a javascript function.
In javascript function remember to assure that dom has been fully loaded then you can manage your accordion